# Google Maps Reload HTML Markers From List of Dom Items with Data Attributes

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a follow-up question to my post [How to Populate a Google Map with HTML markers (Overlay) using data attributes from DOM elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807581/how-to-populate-a-google-map-with-html-markers-overlay-using-data-attributes-f).

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vz9pda8v/   **UPDATED** Please see my my 'answer' for the code that is in this fiddle.

In the fiddle I have it set up so that there are two buttons:

1. The first is set to remove a DOM item that is being used to populate the map via data attributes
2. The second is supposed to reload the markers (which I've based off of: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/p646xmcr/)

**My Issue**

The function that I'm using to reload the markers, `reloadMarkers()` doesn't seem to be working. I'm not sure if the array that I'm creating from the DOM elements is getting created correctly or if the `setMap()` bit is re-running on every I try to reload the markers from the initial marker array instead of from the updated one.

**My JS:**

```
$( "#removeFirst" ).click(function() {
    $('.first').remove();
    console.log('removed first item');
});

function HTMLMarker(lat, lng, text) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
    this.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    this.text = text;
}

HTMLMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
HTMLMarker.prototype.onRemove = function() {}

//init your html element here
HTMLMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {
    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.className = "htmlMarker";
    div.innerHTML = this.text;
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
    this.div = div;
}

HTMLMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
    var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    this.div.style.left = position.x + 'px';
    this.div.style.top = position.y - 10 + 'px';
}

// Make Plot Points From Results DOM Elements
function makeMapPlotPoints() {

    // Set marker from results list and create empty plot point array
    var mapPlotPointDOM = $(".listing-item");
    var mapPlotPointArr = [];

    $(mapPlotPointDOM).each(function() {
        if ($(this).data("marker-lat") !== '') {
            mapPlotPointArr.push([
                $(this).data("marker-id"),
                $(this).data("marker-lat"),
                $(this).data("marker-lng"),
            ]);
        }
    });
    setMarkers(mapPlotPointArr);
};

var map;
var markers = []; // Create a marker array to hold markers

//create empty LatLngBounds object
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var center = {
    lat: 0,
    lng: 0
};

var overlay;

function setMarkers(locations) {

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        var mapMarkerItem = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(mapMarkerItem[1], mapMarkerItem[2]);

        //to use it
        var htmlMarker = new HTMLMarker(mapMarkerItem[1], mapMarkerItem[2], mapMarkerItem[0]);
        htmlMarker.setMap(map);

        // Set Map Bounds to Auto-center
        bounds.extend(myLatLng);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);

        // Push marker to markers array
        //markers.push(marker);
        markers.push(htmlMarker);
    }
}

function reloadMarkers(locations) {

    // Call set markers to re-add markers
    console.log(markers) // Markers after reload
    console.log('Count DOM items before:'+ markers.length); // Markers count after reload


    // Loop through markers and set map to null for each
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }

    // Reset the markers array
    markers = [];


    console.log(markers) // Markers after reload
    console.log('Count DOM items after:'+ markers.length); // Markers count after reload

    // #### NOTE #### This is where I'm getting hung up

    // Call set markers to re-add markers
    setMarkers(locations);
    makeMapPlotPoints();
}

function initializeMap() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 18,
        minZoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, -30),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    makeMapPlotPoints();
    document.getElementById('reloadMarkers').addEventListener('click', reloadMarkers);

}

initializeMap();
```

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a javascript error in your fiddle: `Uncaught ReferenceError: mapPlotPointArr is not defined`, that array is local to the `makeMapPlotPoints` function.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @geocodezip  I've gone ahead and updated both my fiddle and the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I don't assume that this will be a final and thoroughly correct answer. However, I have managed to figure out that each time I was reloading the markers, it was re-adding pre-existing markers (not sure why yet).

By using `.remove()` for all of the html markers in my map before calling the function that generates the markers (within the function that plots the markers), I am able to get this working tentatively.

My fiddle again: https://jsfiddle.net/vz9pda8v/

The code:

```
$( "#removeFirst" ).click(function() {
    $('.first').remove();
    console.log('removed first item');
});

function HTMLMarker(lat, lng, text) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
    this.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    this.text = text;
}

HTMLMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
HTMLMarker.prototype.onRemove = function() {}

//init your html element here
HTMLMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {
    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.className = "htmlMarker";
    div.innerHTML = this.text;
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
    this.div = div;
}

HTMLMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
    var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    this.div.style.left = position.x + 'px';
    this.div.style.top = position.y - 10 + 'px';
}

// Make Plot Points From Results DOM Elements
function makeMapPlotPoints() {

    // Set marker from results list and create empty plot point array
    var mapPlotPointDOM = $(".listing-item");
    var mapPlotPointArr = [];

    $(mapPlotPointDOM).each(function() {
        if ($(this).data("marker-lat") !== '') {
            mapPlotPointArr.push([
                $(this).data("marker-id"),
                $(this).data("marker-lat"),
                $(this).data("marker-lng"),
            ]);
        }
    });
    setMarkers(mapPlotPointArr);
};

var map;
var markers = []; // Create a marker array to hold markers

//create empty LatLngBounds object
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var center = {
    lat: 0,
    lng: 0
};

var overlay;

function setMarkers(locations) {

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        var mapMarkerItem = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(mapMarkerItem[1], mapMarkerItem[2]);

        //to use it
        var htmlMarker = new HTMLMarker(mapMarkerItem[1], mapMarkerItem[2], mapMarkerItem[0]);
        htmlMarker.setMap(map);

        // Set Map Bounds to Auto-center
        bounds.extend(myLatLng);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);

        // Push marker to markers array
        //markers.push(marker);
        markers.push(htmlMarker);
    }
}

function reloadMarkers(locations) {
$('#map-canvas .htmlMarker').remove();
    makeMapPlotPoints();
}

function initializeMap() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 18,
        minZoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, -30),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    makeMapPlotPoints();
    document.getElementById('reloadMarkers').addEventListener('click', reloadMarkers);

}

initializeMap();
```

Would love to know if anyone else has a better solution and thanks in advance!