# 1 Different Map Per Page Using Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a site, and I'm looking to have 1 different Google Map on each page for a list of multiple pages. But I'm unsure as to how to go about this. I'm using a bit of code I found (Listed below.), on W3Schools, but the code they have is for one map on a single page, and multiple maps on a single page. I can't repeat the first function of Javascript even though I show it twice below, because it won't show up on other pages. There may be a way to rewrite it to get it to work, but I'm somewhat new to Javascript.

I've looked for this question, but couldn't come to find one relating to this, only how to create multiple maps per one html file.

I'm using this piece of **Javascript** on my main.js file rather than using the snippet on each separate page. This is a bit of code I found off of W3Schools. The only change I made was I copied and pasted the function and it's containing code twice -

```
function myMap() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map1");
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom: 5
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
}

function myMap() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map2");
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.859822,-97.15901),
    zoom: 5
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
}
```

And I'm using this piece of **HTML** on my first HTML page -

```
<div id="map1" style="width:100%;height:500px"></div>
```

And this one on my second -

```
<div id="map2" style="width:100%;height:500px"></div>
```

As found here on their website -http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trymap_basic.

And as mentioned in the title I'm referencing the Google Maps Javascript API.

This is my structure to call the files I'm using, that I place on each HTML sheet.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo|Roboto:100,300,500" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap">  </script>
```

Comment: What problem are you having?  Why would putting a single map on multiple single pages be an issue?

Comment: I'm trying to place the Javascript in my external file rather than on each page.

Comment: What javascript? What external file? How are you including that external file?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Geocodezip, my apologies for that. I edited the question above. I'm using a blank external Javascript file to hold the Javascript needed, rather than placing the same bit of Javascript on each page.

Comment: What is a "blank external Javascript file"?

Comment: Geocodezip, sorry once again. I was reading that incorrectly to myself. What I meant was I have an external file holding the Javascript code shown in the first snippet.

Comment: How are you including that in the files (should work).

Comment: Check the question again. I just edited it.

Comment: Why are you including `myMap` twice in main.js?

Comment: I wanted to create two maps, one per each page. But based on how I'm not as familiar with Javascript, I'm unsure how to rewrite it to include the two maps. My first attempt was that. But that would be incorrect due to declaring the same function twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one function with a given name in a scope.  To load the map onto separate pages, if the `<div>` id is the same, you can use the same file with a single function in it:

**main.js:**

```
function myMap() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom: 5
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
}
```

include it in the `<body>` of your pages like this:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/SO_20170108_main.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap"></script>
```

**proof of concept/live example**

- [page1.html](http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_20170108_page1.html)
- [page2.html](http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_20170108_page2.html)
- [common javascript](http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/SO_20170108_main.js)

Comment: Thanks! How would I make two different maps with that? One different location per page.

Comment: You can include data in the page markup to set the map's center.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Example that uses HTML data attributes to place markers on a map: [How to Populate a Google Map with HTML markers (Overlay) using data attributes from DOM elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807581/how-to-populate-a-google-map-with-html-markers-overlay-using-data-attributes-f)

Comment: Thank you for your time in helping me solve my problem! This worked! One last question I have is, how do I replace the custom marker with Google default marker?

Comment: That is a new/separate question.