# Positioning Error With Multiple HTML Markers On Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

Having successfully created a google map with a custom HTML marker using the following code, I am now completely stumped as to how to repeat this functionality to create multiple markers. I've tried many variations on this code, including making every possible variable involved unique but to no avail. What am I doing wrong here?

**Initialised Map:**

```
  // Import Style JSON
  var styleVar = []; $.getJSON('json/map-style.json', function (data) { $.each(data, function (key, value) { styleVar.push(value) }) });

  // Define Position
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.97, -71.88);

  // Init Map
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-container'), {
    center: myLatLng,
    zoom: 9,
    maxZoom: 12,
    minZoom: 9,
    styles: styleVar,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.READMAP
  });
```

**Create Marker: ( Working )**

```
  // Create Marker
  function HTMLMarker1(lat1,lng1){ 
    this.lat1 = lat1; 
    this.lng1 = lng1; 
    this.pos1 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat1,lng1); 
  }

  HTMLMarker1.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  HTMLMarker1.prototype.onRemove = function(){}

  HTMLMarker1.prototype.onAdd = function(){
      div1 = document.createElement('DIV');
      div1.className = "marker-div";
      div1.innerHTML = "<div class='marker-inner'></div>";
      var panes1 = this.getPanes();
      panes1.overlayImage.appendChild(div1);
  }

  HTMLMarker1.prototype.draw = function(){
      var overlayProjection1 = this.getProjection();
      var position1 = overlayProjection1.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos1);
      var panes1 = this.getPanes();
      panes1.overlayImage.style.left = position1.x + 'px';
      panes1.overlayImage.style.top = position1.y - 30 + 'px';
  }

  markerLat1 = '42.3';
  markerLng1 = '-72.88';
  var htmlMarker1 = new HTMLMarker1(markerLat1, markerLng1);
  htmlMarker1.setMap(map);
```

**Second Marker: ( Not Working )**

```
  // Create Marker
  function HTMLMarker2(lat2,lng2){ 
    this.lat2 = lat2; 
    this.lng2 = lng2; 
    this.pos2 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat2,lng2); 
  }

  HTMLMarker2.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  HTMLMarker2.prototype.onRemove = function(){}

  HTMLMarker2.prototype.onAdd = function(){
      div2 = document.createElement('DIV');
      div2.className = "marker-div";
      div2.innerHTML = "<div class='marker-inner'></div>";
      var panes2 = this.getPanes();
      panes2.overlayImage.appendChild(div2);
  }

  HTMLMarker2.prototype.draw = function(){
      var overlayProjection2 = this.getProjection();
      var position2 = overlayProjection2.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos2);
      var panes2 = this.getPanes();
      panes2.overlayImage.style.left = position2.x + 'px';
      panes2.overlayImage.style.top = position2.y - 30 + 'px';
  }

  markerLat2 = '41.3';
  markerLng2 = '-71.88';
  var htmlMarker2 = new HTMLMarker2(markerLat2, markerLng2);
  htmlMarker2.setMap(map);
```

The result of this is showing the both markers but with an error in the positioning, the second marker is 'glued' to the first both are taking the positioning of the latter..

Comment: related question: [Adding Custom Markers (HTMLMarkers) to Clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434206/adding-custom-markers-htmlmarkers-to-clustering)

Comment: related question: [How to Populate a Google Map with HTML markers (Overlay) using data attributes from DOM elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807581/how-to-populate-a-google-map-with-html-markers-overlay-using-data-attributes-f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more digging I found another question here that tackles this directly -

[Google Maps: Multiple Custom HTML Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196855/google-maps-multiple-custom-html-markers)

In the hope it'll be helpful to others I'm posting the full code as far as my example goes, nb this can be made much slimmer using arrays etc ( see here for reference to this: https://codepen.io/bipin_peter/pen/PNXNpw )

Hope this helps!

```
  // Create Marker
  function HTMLMarker(lat,lng){ 
    this.lat = lat; 
    this.lng = lng; 
    this.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markerLat,markerLng); 
  }

  HTMLMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  HTMLMarker.prototype.onRemove = function(){}

  HTMLMarker.prototype.onAdd = function(){
      this.div = document.createElement('DIV');
      this.div.className = "marker-div";
      this.div.innerHTML = "<div class='marker-inner'></div>";
      this.div.style.position='absolute';
      var panes = this.getPanes();
      panes.overlayImage.appendChild(this.div);
  }

  HTMLMarker.prototype.draw = function(){
      var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
      var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);
      var panes = this.getPanes();
      this.div.style.left = position.x + 'px';
      this.div.style.top = position.y + 'px';
  }
  markerLat = '41.3';
  markerLng = '-73.88';
  var htmlMarker = new HTMLMarker(markerLat, markerLng);
  htmlMarker.setMap(map);


  // Create Marker
  function HTMLMarker1(lat,lng){ 
    this.lat = lat; 
    this.lng = lng; 
    this.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markerLat1,markerLng1); 
  }

  HTMLMarker1.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  HTMLMarker1.prototype.onRemove = function(){}

  HTMLMarker1.prototype.onAdd = function(){
      this.div1 = document.createElement('DIV');
      this.div1.className = "marker-div";
      this.div1.innerHTML = "<div class='marker-inner'></div>";
      this.div1.style.position='absolute';
      var panes = this.getPanes();
      panes.overlayImage.appendChild(this.div1);
  }

  HTMLMarker1.prototype.draw = function(){
      var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
      var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);
      var panes = this.getPanes();
      this.div1.style.left = position.x + 'px';
      this.div1.style.top = position.y + 'px';
  }
  markerLat1 = '40.3';
  markerLng1 = '-72.88';
  var htmlMarker1 = new HTMLMarker1(markerLat1, markerLng1);
  htmlMarker1.setMap(map);
```